# How to tell if a link is a YouTube url and extract the video id in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an `<input type="text">` field where the user can paste a YouTube url into. Valid values are:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID  // Regular url
http://youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID      // No "www"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID // With ssl
https://youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID     // ssl but no "www"
www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID         // No http(s) at all but with "www"
youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID             // No http(s) and no "www"
https://youtu.be/VIDEO_ID                // Shortened version with ssl
http://youtu.be/VIDEO_ID                 // Shortened version without ssl
youtu.be/VIDEO_ID                        // Shortened version without protocol
```

Where VIDEO_ID is the id of the video obviously which can be a random string, like e.g. `ROjxlXgFbs4`.

As you can see there are quite a lot of variants the user could post into that input field.

So, basically I need a function like this:

```
// Returns false if invalid YouTube URL. If url is valid, returns video id.
function getId(url) {}
```

So it can be used like this:

```
let url1 = "foo";
let url2 = "https://youtu.be/123";

let res1 = getId(url1); // returns false
let res2 = getId(url2); // returns 123
```

**I have seen similar questions on SO but I don't think they cover all the url variants. I could probably code something that works but it would most likely get very ugly. Is there a smart way to do this with as few code as possible, e.g. with regular expressions?**

Comment: seems like it is 2 basic reg exps with optional parameters.

Comment: You only have 2 distinct patterns there - as in all those variants can be checked with 2 regex's (assuming your variants really *are* all variants of youtube uris)

Comment: `//www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID` is valid too

Comment: Should it extract valid URLs from arbitrary strings? I.e. should it return false for "somerandomstring//youtu.be/VIDEO_ID?somequerystring=1" or get the link anyway?

Comment: @ppajer Should return false in that case because that's an invalid url obviously

Comment: I think as long as you can extract video id from a youtube url, you can consider it valid. In any case, once you have video id, you can construct valid url's from it in the way you want.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Well, how do you know if there is a valid id in the string?

Comment: I have added a basic approach to it as an answer below.

Comment: You have **only two variants**: `v=X` and `/X` where `X` is the the video ID. Thinking about it this way will make it easier to be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
checkurl=url=>url.replace("http://","").replace("https://","").replace("www.","").replace("youtu.be/","youtube.com?v=").slice(0,14)==="youtube.com?v=";
```

Remove all unnecessary stuff, and check for the rest...

Comment: To be honest, I like this solution. It's not the supersmartest regex but it's simple, easy to understand and looks pretty solid.

Comment: @timo and if you take the replaced code ( remove the ===...) you already have a solid way of calling the youtube api without causing protocol errors etc.

Answer (score 5):

```
/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?v=|youtu.be\/)(\w+)$/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider only your mentioned url's as valid url patterns, then it's easy to validate a given url and extract VIDEO_ID from it.

Assuming that youtube video_id is 11 characters long, you can use following code for this:

[Here is a question that discusses about length of youtube video id's being changed in future](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13854/are-youtube-codes-guaranteed-to-always-be-11-characters)

```js
/*
If only these url's are to be considered valid, then this becomes quite easy

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID  // Regular url
http://youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID      // No "www"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID // With ssl
https://youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID     // ssl but no "www"
www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID         // No http(s) at all but with "www"
youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID             // No http(s) and no "www"
https://youtu.be/VIDEO_ID                // Shortened version with ssl
http://youtu.be/VIDEO_ID                 // Shortened version without ssl
youtu.be/VIDEO_ID 
*/


$("#get-id").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $("#url").val().trim();
  console.log( url );
  var videoId = "";
  if( url.indexOf("youtube") !== -1 ){
    var urlParts = url.split("?v=");
    videoId = urlParts[1].substring(0,11);
  }else if( url.indexOf("youtu.be") !== -1 ){
    var urlParts = url.replace("//", "").split("/");    
    videoId = urlParts[1].substring(0,11);
  }
  if( videoId === "" ){
    alert("Could not extract video id. Seems invalid url");
  }else{
    alert("Video Id is: " + videoId );
  }
});//#get-id click()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="url" />
<button id="get-id">Get Video Id</button>
```

Comment: I wouldn't count on the video id having length 11 forever

Comment: But I think YouTube video id's are 11 characters long always.

Comment: Yeah, but it's possible that Google changes it to longer id's in the future.

Comment: But it has been using 11 character long id's since beginning I think. And it does not seem to happen anytime too soon.

Answer (score -1):

```
const parseVideoID = (url) => {
  let videoID = url
    .replace("http://", "")
    .replace("https://", "")
    .replace("www.", "")
    .replace("youtu.be/", "youtube.com/watch?v=")
    .split("/")
    .splice(1)
    .join("");

  videoID = videoID.substring(8, 19);

  return videoID;
};
```